# simple image slider in jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I found some code for an 'image slider' on this site, which I'm trying to change to suit my needs. I want to be able to step through 3 or 4 image files, but I'll settle for two, until I get this code sorted.

Could you help me fix this code? I have two images, img1_on.png and img2_on.png.

```
<img id ="rotate_images" src="img1_on.png"/>

$('rotate_images').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img1_on.png')
            ? 'img2_on.png'
            : 'img1_on.png';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

It worked when instead of $('rotate_images').on I had $('img').on. So I get what's happening - 'when you click on any image on the page, if the current image isn't img1_on.png, then show img1_on.png...but I want the code to apply to a SPECIFIC div of images, not any image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Change your selector to:

```
$('#rotate_images')..
```

You forgot the `#`

Comment: Aha! Thanks for that, silly me. Now...would it be easy to add another image? I'm going to experiment with adding another few lines underneath like: var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img2_on.png')
            ? 'img3_on.png'
            : 'img2_on.png'; 
         $(this).attr('src', src);   Thanks again.